# How to print password protected pdf?

Tags: android, pdf, printing, passwords

```
  PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, final ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, final WriteResultCallback callback) {
                    Log.i("Write", "I Visited in Write");

                    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            InputStream input = null;
                            OutputStream output = null;
                            try {

                                String myUrlStr = Constant.URL_FILE + publisherId + "/" + filePath;
                                URL aURL = new URL(myUrlStr);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                conn.connect();
                                input = conn.getInputStream();
                                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                              /*  byte[] key = generateKey(password);
                                byte[] decode = decodeFile(key, buf);*/
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                                }

                                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                                ee.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (input != null)
                                        input.close();
                                    if (output != null)
                                        output.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });
  }

                @Override
                public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

                    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                        return;
                    }

                    PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(getString(R.string.app_name) + " - " + filePath).setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

                    callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
                }
            };
            return pda;
        }

 PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) PreviewPdfActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
            String jobName = PreviewPdfActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
            printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
```

With the above code I am able to print pdf from server url properly but if the pdf from server URL is password protected then Logcat  displays error of cannot print password protected pdf. So can anyone please help me to find the solution. I googled a lot for solution but did not found any appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save the pdf that you receive from the server. Then use iText library to read and print it's content. Something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("path of pdf file with lock","password".getBytes());
```

iText dependency : `compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'`

[iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but wanna ask can I directly print pdf using iText library from server or from internal storage or I will have to create Pdf first

Comment: You will need to create pdf first. If you can print without entering the password, whats the point of password:)

Comment: No I don't think so this solution would be appropriate because in most of the cases iText does not extract images from pdf properly so please suggest me any other solution if you have and yeah thanks for your answer once again.